# Cut out object from image with pen tool

Tags: affinity-designer

I've made an outline with the pen tool, how do I cut out the image so nothing outside of the selection shows?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a closed curve. Give to it white fill, no stroke.

Hints: You need less nodes and get smoother result if you practice to draw handles to the nodes. Many of us have sharpened this skill in Photoshop or GIMP where background removals can be done in the same way. It's actually the most effective method when the background is complex and colors nor contrasts cannot be used for making a selection. Lock the image layer to prevent accidental moving!

Here a coarse curve is drawn and filled with white:

[image]

By right-clicking the curve in the layers panel one gets a bunch of options. One of them is "Mask to Below". Selecting it creates a vector mask to the underlying layer:

[image]

In bigger size you see it's far from perfect. But the curve is still editable and you can also release the mask by moving the curve icon back to own layer.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to do this is making the image layer as a child layer of your vector layer. It will basically clip the image according to the vector layer (GIF is attached for better understanding).

To do so, just drag the image layer (named "Car" in layers panel) on the vector layer's name which is "Curve". (If you drag it on the thumbnail of vector layer, that would result in a different behavior).

Doing so will make the layer "Car" as a child layer and it will give the result you need.

(I've given vector layer a blue color just to make it clear. Otherwise, color is not required.)

[image]

Note: It works on Affinity Designer V2. I'm usure about earlier versions.